# Retrieving current item in lazyrow

Tags: android, state, android-jetpack-compose

I wish to create a `LazyRow` where one of the items will be higher in elevation than the others, as in essentially focused. Now, as I scroll, I wish to highlight the next item with elevation. What I want is something like, the first visible item in the Row, currently, shall be elevated above others. Any ideas?

Comment: If I am able to retrieve the current item, then I can easily implement it

Comment: Then I will be inevitable!!

Comment: What is the "current item" ? Can you use the firstVisibleItemIndex ?

Comment: Oh! I even saw this in the code completion but thought it was something else. Wait I'll give it  a try. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. Sure works! Doesn't really give the hovering effect, but that shouldn't be much of a fuss to implement.

Comment: Why don't you provide it as an answer?

Comment: So you see I wish to animate the size of the focused item, but the `firstVisibleItemIndex` triggers kinda abruptly. Can we do it something like... As I scroll to the next item, the size of the focused-to-be item starts increasing, and the currently focused item decreases in size.

Comment: You got any ideas for that?

Comment: Also, there's little spacing between the Row items. Can the focused item be made to overlap the adjacent ones?

Comment: I wonder if it even can be achieved with `LazyRow`

Comment: You could use the animateContentSize modifier but I have to try it.

Comment: The Overlap wouldn't work, and also, it will not be able to achieve the continuous effect, as in if the user stops half-way, and then decides to swipe back, the effect wouldn't persist. A calculated `lerp` like thing is needed here.

Comment: yes, currently it not so easy to obtain this use case.

Comment: I did manage to make a rough sketch. Looks pretty smooth

Answer (score 2):

To get first visible index from list, You can use the [`LazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState#firstVisibleItemIndex()) property.

Official guide regarding the [Lists: Reacting to scroll position](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#react-to-scroll-position)

> For simple use-cases, apps commonly only need to know information
> about the first visible item. For this **LazyListState** provides the
> `firstVisibleItemIndex` and `firstVisibleItemScrollOffset` properties.

Comment: Very thoughtful of you @Nikunj. But I'm sorry I still cannot mark it as the answer because a), Gabrielle had already answered it in the comment above, and b) I need something more here, as required by the specific use-case described in the question, and as I have mentioned in the comment above. But Thanks for the answer, and the info. Appreciate it